# Cleaning up file based variables. ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am using **gitlab-ci** to automate build and release. In the last job, I want to upload the artifacts to a remote server using **lftp**.

`$(pwd)/publish/` address is the artifacts that were generated in the previous job. And all variables declared in the **gitlab** *Settings --> CI / CD*.

This the job `yaml` code:

```
upload-job:
    stage: upload
    image: mwienk/docker-lftp:latest
    tags:
        - dotnet
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - lftp -e "open $HOST; user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD; mirror -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose --delete $(pwd)/publish/ wwwroot/; bye"
```

Note that **lftp** transfers my files, however, I'm not sure all of my files are transferred.

I added `echo "All files Transfered."` but it never runs.

There is no error and warning in the pipeline log but I got the following error:

[image]

I don't know what is it for. Have anyone faced the error and have found any solution?

Comment: It doesnt transfer everything btw. I had this issue too, this is what I have done:

lftp -p 22 -e "open $SERVER_HOST; user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD; set ssl:check-hostname no; rm -r $SERVER_PROJECT_DIR/*; mirror -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose --delete ./publish $SERVER_PROJECT_DIR; bye"

Comment: did you also make sure that your ftp account has all access/write rights in the folders? you might need to chmod the directory and all its files and subdirectory

Comment: @MrJami the script you suggested doesn't work. The user has full control of the destination folder.

Comment: it didnt work at all? my gitlab runner just used it 2 mins ago and it worked. Or do you mean you got the same error?

Comment: @MrJami it works like the current one in the question.

Comment: @MrJami may you share the rest code of your job?

Comment: this was the end line of my job. I just had this task before I upload the files:

- dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish $CI_PROJECT_DIR/project.sln

Comment: try to do the gitlab-ci locally. Using a terminal. build the project and try to upload the files using lftp. Maybe your terminal will give you an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by some changes in **lft** command parameters.

The point in troubleshooting `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1` is that to use commands with the `verbose` parameter that return sufficient log to enable you to troubleshoot the problem. Another important point is to know how to debug shell scripts such as `bash`, `powershell`, or etc.

Also, you can run and test commands directly in a **shell**, it is helpful.

The following links are helpful to troubleshoot command-line scripts:

[How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script?newreg=252b5d2c744a4f75ad6718f393d6df44)

[5 Simple Steps On How To Debug a Bash Shell Script](https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/debug-script/#what-are-the-3-types-of-scripting-errors)

[Use the PowerShell Debugger to Troubleshoot Scripts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-the-powershell-debugger-to-troubleshoot-scripts/)

For **lftp** logging:

[How to enable lftp protocol logging?](https://superuser.com/questions/712816/how-to-enable-lftp-protocol-logging)